# Is it possible to save the primary key value of more than one fields of a model into an another model's single 'field' using foreign key relation?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

models.py:

```
import datetime
from django.db import models
from pygments.lexers import get_all_lexers


LEXERS = [item for item in get_all_lexers() if item[1]]

class Classname(models.Model):
    class_name = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.class_name

class Sectionname(models.Model):
    class_name = models.ForeignKey(Classname)
    section_name = models.CharField(max_length=1, default='A')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.section_name

class Teachername(models.Model):
    field = """ I want to define here a foreign key field(inherited from Sectionname model)which saves the primary key value of row corresponding to two fields (class_name, section_name) above."""
    teachname = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='teacher Name')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.teachname

class Attendancename(models.Model):
    teacher_name = models.ForeignKey(Teachername)
    date = models.DateField('Date')
    intime = models.TimeField('IN-TIME')
    outtime = models.TimeField('OUT-TIME')

    def hours_conversion(self):
        tdelta = (datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(),self.outtime) - datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(),self.intime))
        hours, minutes = tdelta.seconds//3600, (tdelta.seconds//60)%60
    return '{0}hrs {1}mins'.format(hours, minutes)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" %self.teacher_name
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Classname, Sectionname, Teachername, Attendancename

class ClassnameForm(ModelForm):
    class_name = forms.CharField(max_length=8)
    class Meta:
        model = Classname
        fields = ('class_name',)

class SectionnameForm(ModelForm):
    class_name = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Classname.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = Sectionname
        fields = ('section_name', 'class_name',)

class TeachernameForm(ModelForm):
    field = """ Here I also want to do the same thing, I tried to make a form field, which shows value of both 'section_name' and 'class_name' from above model but only saves the value of corresponding row's primary key."""
    class Meta:
        model = Teachername
        fields = ('classname', 'secname', 'teachname',)

class AttendancenameForm(ModelForm):
    teacher_name = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Teachername.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = Attendancename
        fields = ('teacher_name', 'date', 'intime', 'outtime',)
```

I'm trying to save the 'pk' value of Sectionname model fields(`'calss_name'`, `'section_name'`) into Terachername model's single `'field'`, I also want to show the both the values to user using form field `'field'`, but behined the scenes only primary key values needs to be saved.

Is it possible to do so? If it is then how can I implement it in my app?

Please! provide your suggestions....

Thanks! in advance.....

Comment: Why don't you define `field` as a `ForeignKey` pointing to `Sectionname` model?

Answer (score 2):

You *cannot* store two foreign keys to two different tables in a single `models.ForeignKey` field, and it really wouldn't make any sense (if the reason is not obvious to you then you should learn more about relational model).

But anyway: since a `Sectionname` belongs to one single `Classname`, you don't need anything else than the `Sectionname` pk to get the related `Classname`:

```
class Teachername(models.Model):
    sectionname = models.ForeignKey(Sectionname)
    teachname = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='teacher Name')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.teachname


teacher = Teachername.objects.get(pk=XXX)
print teacher, teacher.sectionname, teacher.sectionname.classname
```

Or if a teacher is supposed to teach more than one section:

```
class Teachername(models.Model):
    sectionnames = models.ManyToMany(Sectionname)
    teachname = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='teacher Name')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.teachname

teacher = Teachername.objects.get(pk=XXX)
for sectionname in teacher.sectionnames.all():
    print teacher, sectionname.classname
```